# Me pueden asistir a identificar que esta mal?

Tags: c++

*La idea es crear una caja registradora de las del supermercado.*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int i=0,j,iva,opc;
    string valor,producto[8][3], otro="SI";
    
        cout<<"\t\t\tBienvenido a su tienda"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n1.VER MENU"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n2.PASAR A LA CAJA "<<endl;
        cout<<"\n3.SALIR"<<endl;
        cout<<"\nELIJA SU OPCION: ";
        cin>>opc;
```

```
    switch(opc){
        
        case 1:
            cout<<"\t\tMenu principal"<<endl;
            cout<<"123 Frijol $2200"<<endl;
            cout<<"124 Aceite $2000"<<endl;
            cout<<"125 Arroz  $2500"<<endl;
            cout<<"126 Leche  $2100"<<endl;
            cout<<"127 Gaseosa $1500"<<endl;
            cout<<"128 Sal    $1800"<<endl;
            cout<<"129 Azucar $2000"<<endl;
            cout<<"130 Pan    $200"<<endl;
            cout<<"Volver a la sala oprime 1"<<endl;
            if (1){
                return main();
                }
            break;

            }
```

```
_Aquí en el caso 2 se pretende que digite el código el producto y el precio, y también si quiere añadir mas productos._
```

```
        case 2:
            do
            {
            i++;
            cout<<"Codigo del producto: ";
            cin>>producto[i][1];
            cout<<"Producto: ";
            cin>>producto[i][2];
            cout<<"Precio Unitario: ";
            cin>>producto[i][3];
```

*Lo que quiero hacer en esta parte es que el programa pueda sumas todos los productos, y dar la factura de todo lo que compro, con el de iva también incluido,  pero no se bien como se puede hacer*

```
            cout<<"\tOtro producto SI o NO: ";
            cin>>otro;
            }while(otro== "SI");
            cout << endl<< endl;
            for(j=1 ; j<=i ; j++)
            {       
            cout <<"\n"<< producto[j][0] << "\t" << producto[j][1] << "\t" << 
            producto[j][2] << "\t";
                valor = producto[j][2]; 
                iva = atoi(valor*_str())
                cout<<"Impuesto= "<<iva*0.15<<end;
            }
            cout<<"Hay otro cliente en la fila  SI O NO: ";
            cin>>otro;
            while(otro = "SI");
                return main();
            for(otro = "NO")
                cout<<"¿Desea saber el valor total vendido en el dia de hoy?"
}
```

*Revise muchos videos y nada, no hacen lo que estoy haciendo*

```
### Errores.
```

65  17  C:\Users\sala 1\Desktop\progrma.cpp [Error] could not convert 'otro.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >(((const char*)"SI"))' from 'std::basic_string' to 'bool'

67  19  C:\Users\sala 1\Desktop\progrma.cpp [Error] expected ';' before ')' token

69  4   C:\Users\sala 1\Desktop\progrma.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token

69  4   C:\Users\sala 1\Desktop\progrma.cpp [Error] expected ';' before '}' token

69  4   C:\Users\sala 1\Desktop\progrma.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token

69  4   C:\Users\sala 1\Desktop\progrma.cpp [Error] expected ')' before '}' token

69  4   C:\Users\sala 1\Desktop\progrma.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token

Comment: Varias cosas. Primero, el código debe pegarse como texto y no como imagen para facilitar la lectura (y en su caso el poder hacer pruebas) a quienes quieran ayudarte. Segundo, si el lenguaje es C++ ¿a qué vienen el resto de etiquetas? Tercero, el error te dice que te falta cerrar algún paréntesis antes. No tiene por qué ser en la línea en la que salta el error, puede ser en cualquiera de las anteriores. Y puede no ser exactamente un paréntesis, sino otro error que confundió al compilador. Sería necesario revisar el código completo.

Comment: Disculpame en verdad es que es mi primera vez publicando algo, y estoy super estresado con este trabajo. Y respecto a eso ya revise y todo los corchetes y me salen mas errores. Disculpame pero no se si me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Haz lo que indiqué más arriba. Edita la pregunta para arreglarla. Pega el código completo pero como texto. Pon una línea de ``` antes y otra después del código para que salga correctamente formateado y coloreado. Copia también como texto los mensajes de error (incluyendo la línea en la que están señalando el error). Veo algo raro en el bucle `do/while`, y es que aparentemente la condición `while` aparece en medio del bloque de código, en vez de al final.

Comment: Si es tu primera vez por aquí, entonces lee [ask], y también [por qué una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/). Además, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y haz caso a lo que te mencionaron más arriba :)

Comment: Listo ya lo arregle para que se vea mucho mejor. De verdad necesito de sus ayudas por que se me ha complicado demasiado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varias cosas mal en el código.

Lo primero, aunque no es importante para el compilador, sí que es importante para las personas que van a leer el código (¡tú entre ellas!): acostúmbrate a indentar el código de forma consistente. Es decir, pon en vertical una bajo otra todas las líneas que forman parte del mismo bloque, e indenta un poco más cuando abras bloque nuevo, y desindenta de nuevo cuando lo cierres. Asegúrate de alinear las llaves que cierran el bloque con la línea en la que el bloque se inició.

Dicho esto, vamos con los errores en sí:

### [Warning] multi-character character constant

La línea:

```
char otro = 'SI';
```

declara una variable de tipo char, pero en cambio intentas meter en ella **dos** caracteres (`'SI'`). Esto es incorrecto, una secuencia de caracteres ya no es de tipo `char` sino de tipo cadena. En ese caso el valor ha de ir entre comillas dobles y no simples, y la variable ha de ser de tipo `string`:

```
string otro = "SI";
```

Este cambio afecta también a la comparación que tienes al final del `do/while`, que debe ser ahora:

```
          }  while(otro == "SI");
```

### [Error] expected ';' before ')' token

Efectivamente, ¿qué se supone que debe hacer esta línea?:

```
          for(j=1 ; j<=i , j++)
```

El bucle está incompleto, pues no tiene cuerpo ¿para qué debería servir? Además delante de `j++` has puesto una coma en vez de un punto y coma. Entiendo que era una parte en la que aún estabas trabajando, y por tanto incompleta. Su sintaxis correcta sería:

```
          for(j=1 ; j<=i ; j++) {
             // ¿qué quieres hacer aquí dentro?
          }
```

### Más errores

Aunque el compilador de momento no te ha dado más errores, tienes otros. Los arrays se indexan desde 0 y no desde 1. Por tanto la parte en que accedes a los elementos `producto[i][1]` etc, está mal ya que llegas a usar `producto[i][3]` que no existe (el último índice posible es 2, pues al empezar en 0 y tener tamaño 3 tendría como índices 0, 1 y 2)

Ese código debe quedar por tanto así:

```
            cout<<"Codigo del producto: ";
            cin>>producto[i][0];
            cout<<"Producto: ";
            cin>>producto[i][1];
            cout<<"Precio Unitario: ";
            cin>>producto[i][2];
```

También te falta añadir `break` como última instrucción dentro de cada `case`.

El código con estas correcciones queda:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int i=0,j,iva,opc;
    string otro = "SI";
    string valor, producto[8][3];
    
    cout<<"\t\t\tBienvenido a su tienda"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n1.VER MENU"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n2.PASAR A LA CAJA "<<endl;
    cout<<"\n3.SALIR"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nELIJA SU OPCION: ";
    cin>>opc;
    switch(opc){
      case 1:
          cout<<"\t\tMenu principal"<<endl;
          cout<<"123 Frijol $2200"<<endl;
          cout<<"124 Aceite $2000"<<endl;
          cout<<"125 Arroz  $2500"<<endl;
          cout<<"126 Leche  $2100"<<endl;
          cout<<"127 Gaseosa $1500"<<endl;
          cout<<"128 Sal    $1800"<<endl;
          cout<<"129 Azucar $2000"<<endl;
          cout<<"130 Pan    $200"<<endl;
          cout<<"Volver a la sala oprime 1"<<endl;
          if (1){
              return main();
          }
          break;
      case 2:
        do
        {
          i++;
          cout<<"Codigo del producto: ";
          cin>>producto[i][0];
          cout<<"Producto: ";
          cin>>producto[i][1];
          cout<<"Precio Unitario: ";
          cin>>producto[i][2];
          
          cout<<"\tOtro producto SI o NO: ";
          cin>>otro;
        }while(otro == "SI");
        cout << endl<< endl;
        for(j=1 ; j<=i ; j++)
        {  // Cuerpo que falta
        }
        break;
      }       
}
```

### Otro potencial problema

Otro "error" es la línea:

```
            if (1){
                return main();
            }
```

Primero, la condición siempre es cierta (pues `if (1)` sólo evalúa la "condición" 1 y un 1 al ser distinto de 0 se considera cierto). Probablemente querías hacer un `cin>>opc;` y después `if (cin=='1')`. Aunque tampoco se entiende muy bien esto, ya que se está obligando al usuario a pulsar 1 y no queda claro qué habría que hacer si pulsa otra cosa.

Por otro lado, al llamar de nuevo a `main()` estás causando una recursión, puesto que la versión de `main()` en la que estabas no llega a retornar, y en cambio se llama a sí misma. Cada vez que una función es llamada (y hasta que retorne) ocupa un marco de pila. En tu caso, cada vez que pase por esa línea se llamará de nuevo (sin retornar nunca) por lo que la pila puede ir creciendo hasta desbordarse (si se ejecuta pocas veces no llegarás a ver este problema).

Si lo que quieres es que vuelva a mostrar el menú, mejor tendrías un bucle que ocupe todo `main()` y que se repita otra vez al llegar a su final, en lugar de hacer la llamada a sí mismo.

El programa está incompleto, pero con estas modificaciones al menos puedes seguir trabajando sobre él. ¡Ánimo!

Comment: Hola muchas gracias si eran todas y cada una de las respuestas que necesitaba, pero ahora como estoy haciendo la segunda parte me sigue quedando mal, me esta explotando la cabeza. Que pena pero no se si me puedas colaborar otra vez, son literalmente la unica esperanza para completar el trabajo @abulafia

Answer (score 0):

He visto 2 posbiles fallos, los cuales son que el Do While tiene al While entre las llaves {} y debería estar afuera

```
do
{
    // Codigo
}
while(condicion)
```

También, los **case** deberías terminarlos con **break**

```
switch()
{
    case 1: break;
    case 2: break;
}
```